# Where should I put common background sync tasks in an MvvmCross project?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

My application needs to sync data from an online source.  It then stores it so it can be used offline.  I am currently calling this from a custom class implementing IMvxAppStart.

```
public class AppStart: MvxNavigatingObject, IMvxAppStart
{
    private readonly IUpdateLocationsService _updateLocationsService;

    public AppStart(IUpdateLocationsService updateLocationsService)
    {
        _updateLocationsService = updateLocationsService;
    }

    public void Start(object hint = null)
    {
        _updateLocationsService.Update();
        ShowViewModel<MainMenuViewModel>();
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is there is no good, cross-platform way to check if I have connectivity or not, and my code crashes if there is no connectivity.  I would like it to just not update.  Where should I perform this type of background task if not here?

I'll probably just catch the error, log it, and move on.  But it seems like a better approach would be to check for connectivity prior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use Network plugin of MvvmCross?
IMvxReachability.IsHostReachable seems does the job

Comment: That looks like just what I need.. so many different nuget packages.. is there one to check gps availability too?

Comment: hmm it appears this plugin doesn't work like the others.. IMvxReachability is unable to be resolved from ioc.. all other plugins it's worked

Comment: it seems that it works only in iOs

`#warning TODO - WINDOWS STORE SHOULD ADD IMvxReachability!
            // Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxReachability, MvxReachability>();`
`#warning TODO - DROID SHOULD ADD IMvxReachability!`

Comment: It's worth remembering that mvx is a community project ... So people can always contribute ... eg one droid reachability implementation is https://github.com/zleao/MvvmCross/commit/e39827639e126b6da22272e43e8f4a3a4fc871d0